# Where have I gone wrong? Generating tictactoe game tree

Tags: c, linked-list, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to generate a tree of tic-tac-toe moves with a linked-list implementation. I am starting the board with three cells filled in, so the tree should have (9-3)! = 720 nodes in total, but after running my program, it quickly hangs. Where have I gone wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {

    struct Node *next_move;
    int cell[3][3];

};

struct Node *root, *position, *temp;
void generate_tree(struct Node *, int move);

int main() {

    root = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof (struct Node));
    root->next_move = NULL;

     root->cell[0][0] = 1;
     root->cell[0][1] = 1;
     root->cell[0][2] = 1;

     generate_tree(root, 1); // computer's next move

    return 0;
}

void generate_tree(struct Node *root, int move) {

    position = root;    // use position to move down the linked list
    print_board(root);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {   // for all cells in root

            if (root->cell[j][i] == 0) { // if cell is empty

                temp = root;    // copy board
                temp->cell[j][i] = move; // make move

                while(1) {  // move to end of list
                    if (position->next_move == NULL) {
                        position->next_move = temp; // link new board at end of list
                        break;
                    } else { // move down list by 1
                        position = position->next_move; 
                        }
                }

                if (move == 1) {    // if it was the computers move
                    generate_tree(position, 2); // call self, with temp as new root, and opponent's move next
                } else {
                    generate_tree(position, 1); // call self, with temp as new root, and computers's move next
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
void print_board(struct Node *node) {

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {

            printf("%d ",node->cell[j][i]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it have less than 6! moves? Not all tic tac toe games end with 9 moves; some finish earlier

Comment: I believe debugging the program is the best solution in such cases

Comment: With a `struct` like that, you can have a linked list. How can you have a tree? A node of a tree needs to be able to have at least two branches.

Comment: btw you need to initialize your other cell values to 0, not all compilers do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, you hit this a second time:

```
while(1) {  // move to end of list
    if (position->next_move == NULL) {
        position->next_move = temp; // link new board at end of list
        break;
    } else { // move down list by 1
        position = position->next_move; 
    }
}
```

The first time you hit it, you replaced `root->next_move` with `root`, turning your list into a single node that points to itself.  The next time, you hit this loop, the first condition will never be met and the loop will not terminate.

It looks like the problem is here:

```
temp = root;    // copy board
```

Surely, this line should be allocating a *new*, *empty* node:

```
temp = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof (struct Node));
temp->next_move = NULL;
```

That's not to say that this will make your program work the way you intended, but it ought to help get past the hang you were asking about.